# Any idea about an iPhone Accelerometer Library?

Tags: iphone, physics, accelerometer

Have looked so long for a library specialized in dealing with iPhone Accelerometer but couldn't find anything.

I have made some few sample apps, but none reaches a level of accuracy as in Labyrinth games for example, so any idea about a library for that? Or maybe an open source app?

Would be better if it's integrated in a Physics library

**UPDATE:** I didn't mention it, but i don't want to use game engines. Specially now, that their future is still unknown. ObjC libraries or tutorials would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend looking at [tweejump](http://github.com/haqu/tweejump). It's basically an open source version of games like Doodle Jump. It really helped me learn how to use the accelerometer to control an object on the screen.

Although you said you didn't want any game engines, this *is* powered by the Cocos2D library. However, Cocos2D is written in Objective-C, so there shouldn't be any issue getting anything powered by Cocos2D passed Apple.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Brian, actually that was exactly what I was looking for, I wanted an ObjC library. And yet open source, that's prefect.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it may just be easier for you to use a game engine that works with iPhone if you are looking to make a game. Here are 2 engines that export to iPhone [GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com/) or [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: I didn't mention it, but i don't want to use game engines. Specially now, that their future is still unknown. ObjC libraries or tutorials would be better.